# ElasticSearch Tire - How to configure to use a value field with date histogram facets?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using the wonderful Tire gem. But, I can't find in the documentation how to to this. Basically, I"d like to add a value field to a date_histogram in Tire. But, I can't seem to make it happy with all options I've tried.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/date-histogram-facet.html

Can this be done currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just pass a `value_field` in the facet definition options hash:

```
Tire.search 'articles' do
  query { match :title, 'foo' }
  facet 'published_on' do
    date :published_on, value_field: 'words'
  end
end
```

I've added some [integration tests](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/5a287819222c4e5cbce8c7a8c0f0053f85b65986/test/integration/facets_test.rb#L130-L142) for this feature.